# A maximization problem involving uniform continuity

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling to find a way to approach this exercise! Assume that ${\bar{\Delta}}(1)$ is the closed unit disk, and consider the function $f:{\bar{\Delta}}(1)\rightarrow {\bf{C}}$ defined by $f(z) = z^2$. Since ${\bar{\Delta}}(1)$ is compact, $f$ is uniformly continuous on ${\bar{\Delta}}(1)$. Given $0<{\epsilon}<2$, find the *maximum* value of $\delta$ such that $|z-w|<{\delta}$ implies $|f(z)-f(w)|<{\epsilon}$. Here the value of $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$. (The answer is ${\delta} = {\sqrt{2-{\sqrt{4-{\epsilon}^2}}}}$.) I tried factoring $|f(z)-f(w)|$ as $(z-w)(z+w)$ but this doesn't seem to help. I can visualize the squaring mapping as a doubling of the argument followed by a shrinking of the modulus. But still have no intuitive feel for how I would maximize $\delta$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem asks that given $|z+w||z-w|=\epsilon, |z|, |w| \le 1$ find $\delta=\max |z-w|$.

By maximum modulus it follows that $|z|=1,|w|=1$ (first fix $w$ and note that $f(z)-f(w)$ being analytic on the unit disc, it attains maximum modulus for $|z|=1$ and now with $|z|=1$ fixed repeat and show that $|w|=1$)

By a rotation we can assume $z=1, w=e^{i\theta}, 0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ hence since $|z+w|=2|\cos \theta/2|$ and $|z-w|=2\sin \theta/2$ we are given $2|\sin \theta|=\epsilon$ and $2\sin \theta/2=\delta$ and we need to find the minimal roots of the equation in $\theta$ given by the above equalities, to ensure that we stay with $|f(z)-f(w)| \le \epsilon$ when $|z-w| \le \delta$

But then $2-\delta^2=2-4\sin^2 \theta/2=2\cos \theta=\pm \sqrt {4-\epsilon^2}$ so  one has $\delta =\sqrt {2 \pm \sqrt {4-\epsilon^2}}$ and of course the minimal $\delta$ is given by the minus sign inside the main square root so we are done!